# Content extract issue in Azure search with blob storage containing image files

Tags: azure-cognitive-search, azure-blob-storage

My requirement is to search thought the "Content inside images" and image content inside pdf.

I have chosen blob storage to keep the all the files. I consists of file types like pdf, xml, text, png, jpeg.

I should be able to search through the content inside the images ( even the image is inside pdf). I see the microsoft documentation that blob storage dont support extracting the content of image files.

I came across the option "AzureSearch_SkipContent", which will allow to search through the metadata of the image (unsupported) files.

**My question is, searching thought the content of the image files is not possible only blob storage or it is not even possible in all the storage options below.
•   Azure SQL Database
•   SQL Server relational data on an Azure VM
•   Azure Cosmos DB
•   Azure Blob storage
•   Azure Table storage**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE May 21, 2018**

This functionality is now available to all customers as a part of Cognitive Search feature of Azure Search.

- [Introduction to Cognitive Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/search/cognitive-search-concept-intro)
- [Process and extract information from images](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/search/cognitive-search-concept-image-scenarios)

*Original response:*

Azure Search is starting a private preview of OCR support for image files in Azure blob storage, as well as images inside PDFs /scanned PDFs. 
If you'd like to participate, please reach out. I'll add contact info as a comment below.

Comment: If you're interested in private preview of OCR in Azure Search, please email me: eugenesh at the usual Microsoft domain. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I cam across this https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/how-to-leverage-ocr-to-full-text-search-your-images-within-azure-search/. Is it not publicly available yet?

Comment: mail sent to participate in private preview, please include me